# Best Version for my iMac - Recommended Version for Mac OS X 10.5.8

Tags: versions

My system:

iMac - Late 2012 version
32 gigabyte RAM
3.4 GHz quad-core Intel i7
NVIDIA GeForce GTX 680MX 2GB

Blender doesn't run correctly.  Lots of long pauses with a spinning icon.

Answer (score 0):

Blender 2.79b is the last stable release before the user interface change happened in 2.8.
Try it. It looks very different and does not have eevee tho